# How can I find a complex Hermitian matrix that does not define an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So far I've been essentially pulling matrices out of a hat, having tried \begin{bmatrix} i+1 & -1 \\ -1 & i+1 \end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ -i & 1 \end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ i & 1 \end{bmatrix}
And trying to determine if they define an inner product by multiplying them by arbitrary \begin{bmatrix} v_1 v_2 \end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix} and trying to produce a negative answer. However, none of these solutions I've tried work, and I'm sure there's a better way of trying to find a solution than by randomly picking matrices.

So, are there any characteristics of matrices that generally lead to them being unable to define an inner product? Do these apply to Hermitian matrices? And does the positive/negativeness of the values of the diagonal affect things?

EDIT - my understanding of a Hermitian matrix was shakey, so I know now that the 1st & 3rd matrices are not actually Hermitian.

EDIT - 
Here is my attempt at proving \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}

\begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 v_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ -i & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} v_1 + iv_2 - iv_1 +v_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} v_1^2 + iv_2^2 - iv_1^2 + v_2^2 \end{bmatrix}  \end{equation}

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: First and third matrices are not hermitian.

Comment: A matrix is hermitian if $a_{ij}=\overline{a_{ji}}$ for all $i,j$, i.e. if its conjugate and its transponse are the same. By the way, if this confuses you, you can find examples even with real matrices (where hermitianity and symmetry coincide). The key point is trying to make $v^HAv\ge 0$ fail.

Comment: The second example does work. The matrix does not define an inner product because it's singular (and $x=\pmatrix{1\\ i}$ is a vector in the null space).

Comment: @user1551 Then I must have done my proof incorrectly. I'll try again and see what happens

Comment: Note also that you should be using $[ \overline{v_1} \ \overline{v_2} ]$, not $[v_1 \ v_2]$.

Comment: Tried the proof again, still not getting anywhere. I'll update my question with what I've done.

Comment: Why not just something simple like $\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$?

Comment: **Hint:** any Hermitian matrix with non-positive eigenvalues will do